# Color Picker how to change TextView

Tags: android

I have a problem.
How to use ColorPickerDialog ?
How do I set ColorPickerDialog so as to change my text color?

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look over this existing code..
http://www.yougli.net/android/a-photoshop-like-color-picker-for-your-android-application/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this project](http://code.google.com/p/android-color-picker/) instead of a demo app

```
// initialColor is the initially-selected color to be shown in the rectangle on the left of the arrow.
// for example, 0xff000000 is black, 0xff0000ff is blue. Please be aware of the initial 0xff which is the alpha.
AmbilWarnaDialog dialog = new AmbilWarnaDialog(this, initialColor, new OnAmbilWarnaListener() {
        @Override
        public void onOk(AmbilWarnaDialog dialog, int color) {
                // color is the color selected by the user.
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel(AmbilWarnaDialog dialog) {
                // cancel was selected by the user
        }
});

dialog.show();
```

Be careful to this (I never used it myself):

> You need to link against Android 3.0 or higher since there is an XML
>   attribute layerType in use. This doesn't mean you can use this only
>   for applications requiring Android 3.0 to operate. It works even in
>   Android 1.6. You just need to select Android 3.0 (API level 11) on the
>   project settings.

Comment: It works, but I have another question. How to save the state after the change of color? Currently, when you press back color to erase.

Comment: If I understand your comment, you need to put your code inside `onOk(Dialog, int)`. The picked color is `int color` and you can store it and do anything you want